# write a function that accepts any number of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know the implementation of how to pass infinite parameters in a function in javascript.

But how to accepts any number of objects as a parameter in function?

I have this:

```
function merge<T>(objA:T, objB: T){
  return Object.assign(objA, objB);
}
```

so that I can do like this:

```
console.log(`${mergeObject2.age},  ${mergeObject2.name}`);
```

But how to declare a function if that number of objects is not known..?

for example this:

```
const mergeObject2 = merge({name: 'Niels'}, {age :39}, {hobby: 'all'});
```

Thank you.

so if I do it like this:

```
const mergeObject2 = merge({name: 'Niels'}, {age :39} );

console.log(`${mergeObject2.age},  ${mergeObject2.name}`);
```

then the output is of course:

39,  Niels

But how to do it if you have more objects..?

Comment: There are considerable differences between doing what you ask in Typescript versus doing it in JavaScript. Which are you actually talking about?

Comment: Why write a wrapper for `Object.assign`?

Comment: *"so that I can do like this"* The code immediately after that statement doesn't merge objects at all and doesn't call your `merge` function. It just creates a string via template literal syntax.

Comment: yes, so typescript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of arguments object available in ES5.
It's just like a variable with type array, and is accessible inside a function.
It contains the values of all the arguments passed to that function.

```
function a(){
  let sum = 0;
  for(let i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
    sum += arguments[i];
  }
  console.log(sum);
}
a(1,2,3);
```

In your case to copy all objects into one, you can do something like this:

```
function a(){
  let finalObj = {};
  for(let i=0;i<arguments.length;i++){
    finalObj = {...finalObj,...arguments[i]};
  }
  console.log(finalObj);
}
a({id:1},{name:"sam"},{age: 25});
```

Comment: yes, thank you. But how to copy then object properties from more than two objects to one object? See my post

Comment: I've edited my answer, you can use the solution added at the bottom.

Comment: AFAIK, using `arguments` is a bit dangerous, because different browsers can handle it in different way. Personally, I don't recommend using of `arguments`. Furthermore, TS is unable to infer `arguments` keyword. It has builtin type `IArguments` but it worthless

Comment: @mightycodeNewton - Don't use the `arguments` pseudo-array. Rest parameters are markedly superior, esp. in TypeScript where they can be properly typed.

Comment: @captain-yossarian - I'm not aware of browsers handling `arguments` in different ways. (There is a loose mode vs. strict mode difference.) What difference have you seen? TIA

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I remember that several years ago I read article with examples of using `arguments` and there was some `inconsistency`. I will try to find this article

Answer (score 3):

Fundamentally, if you want to accept *N* parameters in TypeScript, the varying parameters will all have to have the same type. (It can be a union type, though.) For instance:

```typescript
function myFunction(a: boolean, b: string, ...rest: Array<number | string>) {
    // ...
}
```

(`Array<number | string>` can also be written `(number | string)[]`.)

That function requires at least two arguments (a `boolean` and a `string`) followed by any number of `number` or `string` arguments. Note how the "rest" of the parameters are bundled up in an array, which is why they have to have the same type (`number | string` in the example). Of course, once you're dealing with one specific element from that array, you can use `if` to narrow its type.

If you don't need any fixed parameters (`a` and `b` in the example), just start with the rest parameter.

If you want to use `Object.assign` in the implementation, you'll need to make the first one required (or hardcode `Object.assign`'s first argument). So your `merge` might be:

```
function merge<T extends object>(target: T, ...sources: T[]): T {
    return Object.assign(target, ...sources);
}
const mergeObject2 = merge({name: "Niels"}, {age: 39}); // ¹
console.log(`${mergeObject2.age},  ${mergeObject2.name}`);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAWwKYCcDmqA8AVRVADylTABMBnROAIwCtVoA+ACigEMtUoAuRPABpEAOjGU4IdBFSV+eANoBdAJTzEAbwBQiXYnQ8pSAPIMmUER0qUYmMOy7YowsSIlSZlFQG4tAXy0IBEooFAxsU0ZoACZEAF4w7lYNMA40fgAiADkYVAAbSgy-YQ0ObH4AZgBOPx9A4Lg81BE8uExWAAMAEg00bkjzaMtsYt0evoizGJFUtD8OuqA)

That's basically just `Object.assign` but with the types slightly more restricted (I think), though.

---

¹ You might want to put a `{}` at the beginning to avoid modifying the `{name: "Neils"}` object.